# Boundedness of operators in a domain instead of whole space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $X$ be a Banach function space (for example Lebesgue space, Orlicz space etc.) and $T$ is an operator (For example H-L maximal operator $M$, Calderon-Zygmund operator $K$ etc.)
$$
(1)... \|Tf\|_{X(\mathbb{R}^n)}\leq C \|f\|_{X(\mathbb{R}^n)}
$$
and
$$
(2)... \|Tf\|_{X(\Omega)}\leq C \|f\|_{X(\Omega)}.
$$
Can we say anything about $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$ or $(2)\Rightarrow(1)$ ?

Comment: Do you have $X(\Omega) \subset X(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Do you have $\|f\|_{X(\Omega)} = \|f\|_{X(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ for $f \in X(\Omega) \cap X(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: @gerw assume that $X=L^p$ with $1<p<\infty$. In that case $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset L^p(\Omega)$. What can we say about the question in this special case $X=L^p$.

Comment: My counterexample works in $L^p$ too.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume

- $\def\Rn{\mathbb{R}^n}X(\Omega) \subset X(\Rn)$ and $\|f\|_{X(\Omega)} = \|f\|_{X(\Rn)}$ for $f \in X(\Omega)$,
- $T \, f \in X(\Omega)$ for $f \in X(\Omega)$,

then (1) $\Rightarrow$ (2) is obvious.

However, (most likely) (2) $\Rightarrow$ (1) will not hold, since you have no information on the action of $T$ outside $\Omega$.

Comment: what do you think about the special case $X=L^p$-Lebesgue space with $1<p<\infty$ and $T=M$-Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator. In that case $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset L^p(\Omega)$ and it is well-known that $\|Mf\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}\leq C\|f\||_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$, where $C$ is a positive constant. Can we say that this fact implies $\|Mf\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\leq C\|f\||_{L^p(\Omega)}$ ?

Comment: Does $C$ depend on $C$?

Comment: is it important? I only want to ask is the proposition "$M:L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\to L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is bounded $\Rightarrow$ $M:L^p(\Omega)\to L^p(\Omega)$ is bounded" true ?

Comment: @bjk1806: Oh, I misread your comment. Then it seems to hold.

Comment: I couldn't see how it holds. Can you explain to me?

Comment: You have $\|Mf\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \le \|Mf\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} \le C\,\|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} = C\,\|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}$.

Comment: How can you write the last step, i.e., $\|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}=\|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}$ ?

Comment: Because I extend $f$ from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by zero.

Comment: I am writing what i understand: The function $f\in L^p(\Omega)$ can be extended to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by zero outside $\Omega$. Denote this extension $\tilde{f}$. Then $\|Mf\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\leq \|M\tilde{f}\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}\leq C\|\tilde{f}\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}=\|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}$. How can we write $\|Mf\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\leq \|M\tilde{f}\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ ?

Comment: Because we have $Mf = M\tilde f$ on $\Omega$?

Answer (score 1):

Counterexaple of $(2)\implies (1)$: $\Omega =$ a compact subset of $\Bbb R^n$, $X = $ space of bounded continuous functions with the $\sup$ norm. The operator defined by $Tf(x) = |x|f(x)$ verifies
$$\|Tf\|_{X(\Omega)}\le C\|f\|_{X(\Omega)},$$
but in the whole space:
$$k\in X(\Bbb R^n),\qquad Tk\not\in X(\Bbb R^n)$$
(k = constant function $\ne 0$)